# ionic 2 text not updating after navigation

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic2

i have a button which updates a counter and another button that goes to another page:

```
<ion-content>


<button [navPush]="aboutPage">test</button>
<p>
    {{Counter}}
</p>
<button (click)="clicking()">+</button>

<ion-content>
```

and the code behind:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController } from 'ionic-angular';
import { AboutPage } from '../about/about';

@Component({
  templateUrl: 'build/pages/home/home.html'
})
export class HomePage {
    public aboutPage = AboutPage;
    public Counter: number = 0;
  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController) {

  }

  clicking(){
      this.Counter++;
  }
}
```

1.when click the Back button from About Page(this button is there by default) the + button works behind, the Counter is increasing but the display text on the view is not updating. It is a very simple test and i don't find the issue.

2. When click test button i have to click it twice for it to work, is this a ionic 2 issue?

Thanks,
Gabi S.

Comment: Can you post your Aboutpage? (the .ts file)

Comment: i found the problem, it seems that my AboutPage had the selector added in the Component, i removed it and now it is working as expected, I also did some small other changes which i don't think will affect this behavior

Comment: That was what I was about to answer hahaha, had the same problem myself, also made a stackoverflow question about it ;)

Comment: @Ivaro18 now i am having this problem:
https://plnkr.co/edit/7Q4wDtZjIS1zBDsF0etS
the counter is not updating in the view :|
i am going to make a question about this.

Comment: same issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39581470/ionic-2-not-updating-the-counter-property-in-html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the selector from component is not needed and breaks the app

don't use something more than you need it.