# ionic 2 not updating the Counter property in html

Tags: angularjs, html, angular, ionic2

I have this simple example which does update the Counter value in my HomePage class.

But in the html view:

```
 <p>{{Counter}}</p>
```

this remains zero.

The method:

```
  ondrag(event, item) {
    let percent = event.getSlidingPercent();
    if (percent === 1) {            
        event.close();
        this.Counter--;
    }
    if (percent + 1 === 0) {
        event.close();
        this.Counter++;
    }
}
```

works on my machine if i add logs for each if

Here is the code on plnkr:
https://plnkr.co/edit/7Q4wDtZjIS1zBDsF0etS

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This topic was already discussed in another SO thread: https://stackoverflow.com/a/35106069/2256927

This might resolve your problem!

Comment: thanks for the information, i will have a look at it as soon as possible and let you know if it works

Comment: the main problem is the same like in other GUIs, if you want to update the GUI from another thread you can't, for angular this can be resolved with NgZone

Answer (score 0):

Your `ondrag` handler is attempting to use `item` which is actually a string - literally the iterated value of the `items` array. This means your code is throwing an exception on item.getSlidingPercent which doesn't exist. Try using `event` instead of `item`, like this:

```
  ondrag(event, item) {
    let percent = event.getSlidingPercent();
    if (percent === 1) {   
        event.close();
        this.Counter--;
    }
    if (percent + 1 === 0) {
        event.close();
        this.Counter++;
    }
  }
```

Comment: the problem remains even when using event, the Counter on html remains the same, also on plnkr the value in the class seems that it doesn't change. Thanks for trying, i think the only way to reproduce this is on a local machine